# Place button over google map view

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to display a button on top of my Google Map View on iOS. I am using Xcode and have tried the following code:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView() 

 override func loadView(){
    view = mapView

    do{
        if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json"){
            mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
        }
    } catch {
    }

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.45, longitude: -73.6)
    marker.title = "Montreal"
    marker.snippet = "Canada"
    marker.map = mapView

    onMapReady()

}
```

I do not see any button when the map loads. 
This is what the storyboard looks like:

[Main Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ssh.png)

Here are the constraints:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ZHT.png)

How would I get this button to appear?

Comment: Hello, If you are binding your ViewController with a Storyboard, why do this: self.view.addSubview(refreshButton) ? Doesn't make any sense to me.   
It is something you should continue to manipulate from your storyboard, not in the viewDidLoad, so might you show us your constraints?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by constraints, what should I post?

Comment: I added you below a possible solution

Comment: I've updated my post to show a photo of my constraints. I noticed I don't have a separate view created for the MapView, could that be my problem?

Comment: in the photo you attached, I don't see any constraints driving your button. It's just showing autoresizing stuff. Check my pictures to see the differences (trailing space/top space, and so on...)

Comment: Ok I have added constraints to my button, as shown in the updated link. I still do not see it appear.

Comment: did you check the button visibility? change the background color in black and text color white

Comment: parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have added your button inside the Parent View you can manage the constraints like:

[image]

Instead, if the button is outside and above your Parent View you can use this:

[image]

Comment: I ended up abandoning the storyboard and adding the map and button programmatically in the code. However I did see it work after modifying the constraints. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)